# Loop for NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, applescript, nsslider

I am instituting a NSSlider into my project that needs to call different methods when moved up or down. So if it is moved up it will do one method, which is a AppleScript, and the opposite if moved in the other direction, another AppleScript. Would I do this with an IF loop or something else? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should keep track of the old value of the slider, and then compare with the new one to see if it has moved down or up.

```
- (IBAction)slide:(id)sender {
    float newValue = [slider floatValue];
    if (newValue < oldValue) {
        // moved down
    } else {
        // moved up
    }
    oldValue = newValue;
}
```

Comment: That is great, any idea how to keep track of the value on the slider?

Comment: by using a the global variable **oldValue** mentioned in the code. You initialize it with the initial value of the slider (not shown in the code). And then every time the slider value changes, you update **oldValue** (this is what I did in the line **oldValue = newValue;**